react-native-snap-carouse | ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined, js engine: hermes #1017
After updating my Expo version and other packages, I get this error in Carousel.js;
Here is my code;
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Platform } from "react-native";
import Carousel, { Pagination } from "react-native-snap-carousel";
import Metrics from "../../styles/Dimensions";
import pagination from "./pagination";
const Slider = (props) => {
const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);

const [data, setData] = useState(props.slideDatas);

const _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
return {item.component};
};

return (

    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Carousel
        layout={props.assets ? "stack" : "default"}
        data={data}
        renderItem={_renderItem}
        sliderWidth={373 * Metrics.horizontalScale}
        itemWidth={327 * Metrics.horizontalScale}
        onSnapToItem={(index) => setActiveSlide(index)}
      />
     
        {pagination()}
    </View>
);
};

export default Slider;

Here is the error;
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined, js engine: hermes
enter image description here
I'm sure the error is here because when I remove it from the project, there is no problem. Even if it is installed in the project, it is not a problem, but when I run my code, it gives an error.

please try to reset cache and build the app again. or try using this command
yarn start --reset-cache
let me know if it works.
or you can also try commands mentioned in this link
https://docs.expo.dev/troubleshooting/clear-cache-windows/

I tried it before, now I did it again and the error still ongoing. @MuhammadHassaan

The problem is indeed with the react-native-snap-carousel, and I presume it is related to the new expo update, where given that react-native-snap-carousel is such an old library, some of the dependencies might not be compatible.
The only solution I'm exploring is to use react-native-reanimated-carousel a newer, more efficient, and more flexible library, with which you should be able to generate most carousels created with react-native-snap-carousel. Do bare in mind that this new library is slightly more complex do to the usage of react-native-reanimated, so I suggest to check out some examples before trying to translate your original carousel.
